# how to show excel sheet in flutter application?

Tags: excel, flutter, flutter-dependencies, spreadsheet, pub.dev

I am new on Flutter , i am trying to make application which can read and edit excel sheets as shows in image.

so far i have reached no where.

how to show excel sheet in flutter app and edit it??

is there any way to do it ??

[image]

Comment: take a look of this link : https://fluttergems.dev/ods-xlsx-sheets/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/15383394/bilal-almefleh @BilalAlmefleh i don't know how to use these library. in these library there is example but there is only one dart file. do you have any project for example??